# Change default Windows installer location in Visual Studio

Tags: windows, installation, setup-project, visual-studio-setup-proje

I'm modifying a Windows installer in Visual Studio 2008 (Visual Basic I believe, what my company's currently using) and I want to change the default install "Folder" of the program (the name of the directory). I've attached an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzvsA.png)
 to show what I mean. "Folder" **defaults to "C:\Program Files (x86)\foo\"** and I ***want it to default to "C:\Program Files (x86)\bar\" instead*** every time the installer is run. I feel like I've gone through just about every menu/item in the install directory and everywhere I can find, done my online research, all to no avail. Any help with this or in what window/menu to look in would be very-much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the File System view in the setup project, select Application Folder and then use F4 (or right-click=>Properties window). That will show you the default location. The values in square brackets are Windows Installer properties, the rest are your text.

If you want to get more up to date Visual Studio Community Edition is free and there is an installer project add-on for it that you can get from the Visual Studio extension gallery.

Comment: I solved my problem a few days ago. Can't remember off the top of my head how I did it without seeing the computer in front of me, but it was something trivial in some menu. Thanks for your response though!